# Is it mandatory to open all IPs to insert data to RDS ( MySQL ) from an AWS lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a simple AWS-lambda function which write to RDS ( MySQL ). I was getting could not connect to MySQL error until I opened MySQL port 3306 to all IPs.

Is it mandatory to open all IPs to insert data to RDS ( MySQL ) from an AWS lambda function ? 
If so if there is any security measure that should be taken , please advise. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not mandatory. If you are doing your lambda without VPC configuration settings in lambda console, you would need to open port 3306 for the world (0.0.0.0). But if you dont wanna do that and only want to have your private network or your VPC CIDR range has access to 3306 port, then you must need to put your lambda with VPC configuration

here under the Network options in your lambda console, selec your VPC configuration
[image]

Comment: a picture worth 1000 words

Comment: Very True. I'm glad that my answer worked for you. All the best